# how to access a created swt viewpart plugin in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i am new to eclipse plugins creation, 
and i am trying to create a viewpart ui for eclipse 4.2.
i finished coding it and now i want to see how it looks in eclipse.

however i cant seem to find the place where i can access the newly created view part.

i know where all the views are located, 
but i cant seem to find where in the creation of the viewpart do i specify 
under what category will the view part appear.

where do i define the category under which the view will appear?

or is there another way to access it?

Comment: Have you finished all part of view implementation including the plugin.xml definition? I mean are you asking how you can launch eclipse and see the view you have just created?

Comment: You can create a new run configuration of type eclipse application (Run->Run Configurations..) and launch. There you can see your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views need to be registered using a plug-in extension point. See the [eclipse docs](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_basicext_views.htm). Essentially double click on your plugin.xml (or if not present yet, the MANIFEST.MF) file, select the "Extensions" tab and add a new extension for the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point. Under this you can create an entry for your view. The view entry has a place to specify the category under which to file the view. The org.eclipse.ui.views extension allows allows you to define your own categories.